# Split a file by lines into specific subfolders in bash

Tags: bash, awk, text, split

I have a text file `parent.txt` that contains five lines:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

I would like to split that file into individual files called `child1`...`child5` and for that I can use the `split` command like this

```
spit -l 1 -d parent.txt child
```

However, I would like each newly created file to be located in a folder that has the same name (e.g. file `child1` would be located in folder `child1`) and I don't know how to do it.

For the moment, I wrote this:

```
n=`cat parent.txt | wc -l`;
for i in `seq 1 $n`;
do
    mkdir -p $(printf "child%04i" $i);
    cd $(printf "child%04i" $i);
    split -l 1 -a 4 --numeric-suffixes=1 parent.txt child
    cd ..
done
```

but it outputs every child file in every folder, which isn't what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to do it.

Just for each line, create a directory named `child` + line number, and then print the line into the proper file.

In awk:

```
awk '{system("mkdir child"NR); print > "child"NR"/child"NR}' parent.txt
```

In bash it will be 1000 times slower:

```
nr=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
   mkdir "child$nr"
   printf "%s\n" "$line" > "child$nr/child$nr"
   nr=$((nr + 1))
done < parent.txt
```